# ScanSnap Integration

Tags: scanning

I am currently trying to figure out how to integrate with the fujitsu scansnap scanner and have found no details from fujitsu on how the fujitsu scansnap manager calls your application and send the file to your application.

1.) do the pass a parameter with the filename when they launch your process?

2.) do you just have to look in the target directory?

If anyone has information regarding this type of integration or knows where to get the "white paper" information, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options, the old XP and model right after that (the larger multi paper models) would pass the temp file their file was saved to as the first parameter after the exe name on a custom program -- otherwise yes you can just scan the scan folder, make sure to move the file after it's done scanning so you don't view it again.